# How can I change the original DataFrame from a group?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's suppose I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'label': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a'], 
                   'numbers': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                   'arbitrarydata': [False] * 10})
```

I want to assign a value to the `arbitrarydata` column according to the values in both of the other colums.  A naive approach would be as follows:

```
for _, grp in df.groupby(('label', 'numbers')):
    grp.arbitrarydata = pd.np.random.rand()
```

Naturally, this doesn't propagate changes back to `df`.  Is there a way to modify a group **such that changes are reflected in the original DataFrame** ?

Comment: I don't have an answer as of yet but I think http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation may be what you need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `transform`, e.g.:

```
df['arbitrarydata'] = df.groupby(('label', 'numbers')).transform(lambda x: np.random.rand())
```